# Cannot create Loop cuts

Tags: workflow

I have lost the ability to make loop cuts. When I press CTRL+R, nothing happens. I am not aware of any changes I'd made. It stopped working on BOTH my Macs, both running Sierra 10.12.5.

I tried loading factory reset, using the default blender keyboard layout. When i type "loop" in the search box, it returns nothing. I've tried the new 2.79 RC, same issue.

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like you are not in edit mode xd

Comment: I don't think you need to be in edit mode to add loop cuts...

Comment: fun fact: you do :D

Answer (score 2):

You can only add loop cuts in edit mode (which you can enter either by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> or by choosing it in a mode scroll menu at the bottom).
[image]